# Laravel Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I normally select my items seperatly with Eloquent Laravel

```
$b = Booking::where("id","=",$id)->get();
```

What I get is an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  with one item.
I put them in an array later on so that I have an array of these Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection objects.

However sometimes I need more of them, so I do something like that:

```
$bs = Booking::where("date","=",$today)->get();
```

Now this is a collection with multiple items. Is there an easy way to change a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection of several items in a array of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection with single items?

Sure I can do this:

```
$bs = Booking::where("date","=",$today)->get();
foreach ($bs as $i=>$b) $bs2[] = Booking::where("id","=",$b->id)->get();
```

But selecting again from DB seems to be a quite stupid solution.

EDIT:

If I do this I have:

- $bs  as a 'Collection'-object holding 15 'Booking'-objects inside.
- $bs1 as an Array holding 15 'Collection'-objects with each holding 1 'Booking'-object inside. (that's what I want to have)

->toArray() creates an Array holding 15 Arrays. That's not what I want to have - I need the objects. As the eloquent provides features like a date field is automatically a DateTime object

Comment: Are you looking for  `toArray()` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `toArray()` function and you are ready to go,

```
$bs = Booking::where("date","=",$today)->get()->toArray();
```

Now you will have array of data returned from DB.

Comment: ->toArray creates an Array of Arrays. I need objects inside the Array.Edited my Questionto clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$bs = Booking::where("date","=",$today)->get();
foreach ($bs as $i=>$b) {
    $bs2[] = collect([$b]);
}
```

This gives you an array of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` collections with one item each.

If you need `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` collections:

```
$bs2[] = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection([$b]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
$bs = Booking::where("date", "=", $today)->get();
$new_bs = $bs->toArray();
```

Comment: $new_bs = $bs->toArray();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `->all()` method.
The problem you are experiencing it's because when using `->toArray()`, Laravel converts the collection to an array and the nested object that are an instance of Arrayable are also converted.

It's explained in [here - Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-toarray)

`all()` method in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-all)